# Первый отрицательный элемент массива

Tags: c++, массивы

У меня тут проблемка возникла: надо, чтобы программа выводила только первый отрицательный элемент, `break` использовать запрещено. Как можно записать условие, чтобы оно стало ложным и прекратило дальше выводить элементы (чтобы цикл завершился)?

Вот та часть программы, которую изменить надо:

```
cout << Rus("Первый отрицательный элемент массива: "); 
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) if(a[i]<0) 
{ 
   cout << a[i]<<" "; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
int i = 0;
while (arr[i] >= 0)
    i++;
cout << arr[i];
```

Comment: cout << Rus("Первый отрицательный элемент массива: "); 
for (int i = 0; i < n && a[i] >= 0; i++);
if(i < n) {
    cout << a[i];
}
если отрицательных не вообще, не выводим ничего

Answer (score 0):

```
bool notNegative = true;
for(int i = 0; i < n && notNegative; ++i){
   if(a[i] < 0){
       cin << a[i];
       notNegative = false;
   }
}
```

В данном случае после первого захода в if значение булевой переменной изменится и условие `i < n && notNegative` не выполнится, после чего цикл завершится.